# Aura Iteration is returning 0 rows

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration

I have a below lightning component

Please ignore the commented lines

```
<aura:attribute name="serverResponse" type="ReportsController.COABReportLineItem[]" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>    

    <article class="slds-card">
        <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
            <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                <div class="slds-media__body">
                    <h2>
                        <a class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate" title="[object Object]">
                            <span class="slds-text-heading_small">Report Details</span>
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Full Name">Full Name</div>
                        </th>
                       <!-- <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="COAB Last Modified Date">COAB Last Modified Date</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Note Subject">Note Subject</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Note Description">Note Description</div>
                        </th> -->
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Task Subject">Task Subject</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Task Description">Task Description</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Task Due Date">Task Due Date</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Call Center Agent">Call Center Agent</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!serverResponse}" var="detail">
                        <tr>
                            <td data-label="Full Name">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!detail.ClientName}">{!detail.ClientName}</div>
                            </td>   
                            <!--<td data-label="COAB Last Modified Date">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!detail.Coloum}">value</div>
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Note Subject">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!detail.Coloum}">value</div>
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Note Description">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!detail.Notecription}">{!detail.NoteDescription}</div>
                            </td>   -->
                            <td data-label="Task Subject">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!detail.Subject}">{!detail.TaskSubject}</div>
                            </td>   
                            <td data-label="Task Description">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!detail.TaskDescription}">{!detail.TaskDescription}</div>
                            </td>   
                            <td data-label="Task TaskDueDate">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!detail.TaskDueDate}">{!detail.TaskDueDate}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td data-label="Call Center Agent">
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!detail.CallCentreAgent}">{!detail.CallCentreAgent}</div>
                            </td>   
                        </tr>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </article>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) 
    {
        helper.loadInitData(component, event, helper);
    },
})
```

Helper:

```
({
    loadInitData : function(component, event, helper) 
    {       
        var action = component.get("c.GetCOABReportData");

        if (action == null)
            return;

        action.setParams({ OwnerId : null });

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) 
        {
            var state = response.getState();

            if(state === "SUCCESS") 
            {
                var result = response.getReturnValue();

                component.set("v.serverResponse", result);
                console.log(component.get("v.serverResponse"));
            }
            else if(state === "INCOMPLETE") 
            {
                // do something
            }
            else if(state === "ERROR") 
            {
                var errors = response.getError();

                if (errors) 
                {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) 
                    {
                        console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

apex controller

```
public class ReportsController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<COABReportLineItem> GetCOABReportData(string OwnerId)
    {
        if (OwnerId == null)
        {
            OwnerId=UserInfo.getUserId();
        }
        List<COABReportLineItem> reportData=new List<COABReportLineItem>();
         User COABAgent=[Select AssignedCOABAgent__C from User where Id=:OwnerId Limit 1];

        if (COABAgent == null)
        {
            return reportData;
        }
        else
        {
           List<Task> coabTasks = new List<Task>();
            coabTasks = [SELECT Id,Who.Name, Subject,Description, ActivityDate, Status, OwnerId, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate,LastModifiedById FROM Task where CreatedById=:COABAgent.AssignedCOABAgent__C And OwnerId=:OwnerId];
            if (coabTasks != null)
            {
                COABReportLineItem coabReportLineItem;

                for(Task coabTask:coabTasks)
                {
                    coabReportLineItem = new COABReportLineItem();
                    coabReportLineItem.ClientName      = UserInfo.getUserName();
                    COABReportLineItem.TaskSubject     = coabTask.Subject;
                    COABReportLineItem.TaskDescription = coabTask.Description;
                    COABReportLineItem.TaskDueDate     = coabTask.ActivityDate;
                    COABReportLineItem.CallCentreAgent = coabTask.CreatedBy.Name;

                    reportData.add(COABReportLineItem);
                }   
            }           
            return reportData;          
        }   
    }
}
```

and

```
public class COABReportLineItem {

    @AuraEnabled
    public string ClientName {get;set;}
      @AuraEnabled
    public DateTime COABLastModifiedDate {get;set;}
      @AuraEnabled
    public string NoteSubject {get;set;}
      @AuraEnabled
    public string NoteDescription {get;set;}
      @AuraEnabled
    public string TaskSubject {get;set;}
      @AuraEnabled
    public string TaskDescription {get;set;}
          @AuraEnabled
    public DateTime TaskDueDate {get;set;}
          @AuraEnabled
    public string CallCentreAgent {get;set;}
}
```

In console log I am gettign 2 result snip is attached

[image]

But still aura Iteration is not returning any rows on the page, can someone please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aura:iteration is not written correctly. Items attribute in aura:iteration uses "v." attribute also.

try below -

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.serverResponse}" var="detail">
```

it will work.

ENJOY